# How to include additional lines between x-axis values using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I created x axis with the values ​​and the labels and applied a style in grid lines. The code is below:

```
let xScale = d3.scalePoint().domain(axisXValues).range([0, width]);

let xAxisGenerator = axisXLabels.length > 0 
    ? d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(axisXValues.length).tickFormat((d,i) => axisXLabels[i])
    : d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(axisXValues.length);

chart.append("g")  
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxisGenerator.tickSize(-height));
```

I would like to include more ticks between (green) the values ​​and apply a different style as in the example below:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add **a new linear scale** with the **same range and domain** in the original point scale. (Keeping the original point scale and its rendered axis, of course)

Then calculate the values in between and plot the axis using **`axisBottom.tickValues()`**

Color of the tick line can be changed by accessing **`.tick line`** and applying the **`stroke`** attribute.

**Do note** that this would only work if the **point scale's domain is equally spaced, i.e. linear**.

Adding the following code to yours should work. Attaching a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/shreshthmohan/pen/KKXbaEm?editors=0010) too.

```js
const xScaleInBetween = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(xScale.range())
  .domain(d3.extent(axisXValues));

let xTicks = xScale.domain();
let xTicksInBetween = Array.from({length: xTicks.length - 1},
    (_, j) => ((xTicks[j] + xTicks[j+1]) /2));

chart.append("g")  
    .attr("class", "x-axis-between")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScaleInBetween)
        .tickValues(xTicksInBetween)
        .tickSize(-height))
    .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick line').attr('stroke', 'green'))
    .call(g => g.selectAll('.tick text').remove())
```